# Is there any way to do a counter_cache with an HABTM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, ruby-on-rails-4

All the results I am seeing in Google seem to be from Rails 2.x and 3.0.

Given that Rails 4 is right around the corner, have there been any changes to allow us to use `counter_cache` on a HABTM association?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, nor did I see any issues in the Rails 4 milestone which seem to suggest otherwise. I've been following the development closely, but not religiously. You can always check out the Rails 4 milestone and look a little closer https://github.com/rails/rails/issues?milestone=9, but it wasnt' mentioned in the Rails 4 blog post either at http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/ regarding the first beta.

Answer (score 0):

I created counter_cache functionality for a [HABTM association here](https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/5255300).

If you have any suggestions, feel free to let me know.